# libsasl2 change paths

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, postfix

I have been following the tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix for installing Postfix on ubuntu.

Im stuck at the Authenication section of the tutorial where you change paths to live in the false root,  if you look at the link above I have a file (/etc/default/saslauthd) which is pretty much the same as the one from the tutorial.

**saslauthd**

```
# This needs to be uncommented before saslauthd will be run automatically
START=yes

PWDIR="/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
PARAMS="-m ${PWDIR}"
PIDFILE="${PWDIR}/saslauthd.pid"

# You must specify the authentication mechanisms you wish to use.
# This defaults to "pam" for PAM support, but may also include
# "shadow" or "sasldb", like this:
# MECHANISMS="pam shadow"

MECHANISMS="pam"

# Other options (default: -c)
# See the saslauthd man page for information about these options.
#
# Example for postfix users: "-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
# Note: See /usr/share/doc/sasl2-bin/README.Debian
#OPTIONS="-c"

#make sure you set the options here otherwise it ignores params above and will not work
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

When I run the following command in ubuntu

`dpkg-statoverride --force --update --add root sasl 755 /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd`

I get the following error

```
dpkg-statoverride: warning: An override for '/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd' already exists, but --force specified so will be ignored.
dpkg-statoverride: warning: --update given but /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd does not exist
```

I don't why this is happening, I literally followed the tutorial step by step and have installed all the packages necessary, what could be the problem? do I have to manually create

Answer (score 1):

First of all, they are warnings, not errors.

Second, read the next line:

> This may report an error that "`--update` given" and the
>   `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd` directory does not exist. You
>   can ignore this because when you start `saslauthd` next it will be
>   created.